# Как добавить старую версию сайта на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, редирект

Была старая версия сайта на самописном движке. Сделали редизайн нескольких страниц и натянули их на WP.  Но нужно добавить старые страницы. Как добавить их не делая шаблон этих страниц? Нужно создавать подпапку?

Comment: Нужно импортировать контент из них

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно ими управлять через ВП, то да нужно делать шаблоны страниц и добавлять в них контент через админку, а если нужно что бы они просто были то да никто не мешает создать папку в корне сайта и перекинуть туда самописний сайт.